# Data structure for a set of keys with efficient find-missing

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure that supports the following operations for 
integer keys `k` ranging from 0 to M-1.

- O(1) or O(log n) `insert(k)`, `erase(k)`, `lookup(k)`.
- O(1) or O(log n) for the special operation `find_missing_key()` which returns any key not currently present in the structure.
- O(n) or O(n log n) space. In particular. should not be O(M).

An obvious implementation would be a "list-of-free-keys" structure, implemented as a heap; but that would take O(M) space. Is there some data structure that fulfills all of the requirements?

Comment: What is `n` in your proposed complexity?

Comment: The current size of the data structure.

Comment: Not sure I'm following you. If you have `M` possibilities, that means that space would have to be `O(M)` if you fill up your data structure. Therefore your `n` and `M` would be interchangeable

Comment: I mean that if M = 100,000, and the data structure currently contains 5 elements, then the structure should use about 5 units of memory rather than 100,000.

Comment: That's still `O(M)` because there are `M` possibilities. Big oh represents the asymptotic tendency, meaning it is mainly a good indicator of the worst case scenario which is `O(M)` space for you, regardless of the current amount of items. What you mean is a dynamically growing data-structure.

Comment: @nem Dude you're being pedantic and unhelpful (as well as incorrect).  O(m) and O(n) are very different when m != n, and it has nothing to do with best case or worst case scenario.  Your scenario of m=n is only one special case.  The goal is very well-defined: find an algorithm that does not use m units of space when n is less than m.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman I was just trying to clarify something that was confusing me, didn't meant to be unhelpful. I still don't see how you can store `X` items without `X` amount of space (eventually), unless you find a way to represent multiple elements as a single element. Now I see that your answer demonstrates how to do this by segmenting the key range `M` to represent range groups instead of individual values. Good answer mate, didn't mean to start an argument, just wanted some clarification so I can try to help :)

Comment: @nem That's cool mate, I didn't mean to argue either, sorry if my response came across that way.  I was pointing out that your interpretation of Big O was incorrect, based on your assumption that you would always need M space because that's the worst case scenario.  The primary difference being that with an O(n) algorithm, you are guaranteed that the cost will never go near a factor of m in any situation where n is significantly less than m and this is a guarantee that you don't get with an O(m) algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a binary segment tree.

Each node in the tree represents a range of integers [a,b], and is either a leaf [a,a] or divides into two nodes representing the ranges [a,m] and [m+1, b] where m is (a+b)/2.

Only expand nodes when necessary, so initially we just have a root node for the range [0,M-1] (or [0,M) if you prefer)

In each node, keep a count of how many used/free spots you have in that subtree.

Insertion, lookup, and deletion of x is O(log n): Just keep subdividing until you reach [x,x], and update everything on the path from that node to the root.

find_missing_key is also O(log n): Since you know the size of each segment and how many free elements are in it, you can decide at each node whether to go left or right in order to find a free element.

(EDIT: Incidentally, this also allows you to find the first, or last, or even the i_th free element, at no additional cost.)

Comment: I was typing this up right now, but looks like you beat me to it. :-) The only issue to watch out for is how to store key/value pairs. For that, store a binary search tree in each node storing the key/value pairs. You can split and join those trees in time O(log n) each if you need to split or join two nodes in the tree.

Comment: @templatetypedef Why do you need to store a BST in every node?  Just subdivide until you reach a leaf, and store any key/value information there.